# A book that I'm reading says I've lived is correct instead of I've been living in this sentence

Tags: present-perfect

A) I've lived here since I was two years old.
B) I've been living here since I was two years old.

Someone please explain to me how is the second sentence incorrect here.

Comment: Both look good to me. Who says otherwise and why?

Comment: Why do you think they *both* can't be correct?

Comment: ... This is a third strike; if the book actually says (B) is incorrect, throw it away.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth what do you mean by third strike? The book title is "IELTS Advantages" written by Jon Marks.

Comment: Third strike and you're out. 'I've been living here since ...' is totally acceptable.

Comment: I agree with others that both the "have lived" and "have been living" versions are okay.  I'll suggest that an odd idea some people have is there should only be one correct way to say a thing.  In a case where there seem to be two ways, they must find some reason to condemn one of the ways.

Comment: @john I hope the "third strike and you're out" actually refers to the book. Throw it out; it's been wrong too many times. However, if you're learning English for IELTS, you may be interested in our sister site called [ell.se].

Comment: Three witnesses calling time on the book, to switch and mix metaphors. Unless 'the book' is McCawley, and perhaps even then (it's a bit dated now),, expect some deviations from what is actually considered acceptable nowadays. The snag is, examiners may actually adhere to what some texts claim as gospel (another metaphor).